# Resuming training after a vacation

Tags: pull-ups

My normal workout is 4 sessions of 10-15 pullups.

I took a windsurfer's vacation. I'm an intermediate windsurfer so I had my biceps working 4-5 hours a day. Obviously, the muscles ached slightly because of overtraining. And I did no pull-ups per se during the vacation.

Now, as I'm back from vacation, and I start my normal routine, the muscles hurt sharply as if I never did a pull-up.

Question: is it the right time to resume training (considering this ache as an indication of muscle build-up) or should I give my biceps a rest?

Thanks and sorry for possibly a lame question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Muscles hurt sharply"  OK, give them a rest. Do some stretching on your pull up bar, Lower it if you can and do some modified pull ups and see if you can work off the pain but be careful, you don't want to pull something that will knock you out of working out for a few weeks...